# Detection of Ethernet Protocol

Tags: communication, ethernet

I know Ethernet has a EthernetType bit and that is 2 byte which ethernet protocol can we find. But I am looking for this question: I have two devices and they communicate between `X` ethernet protocol. I said to that talk with Profinet ethernet protocol. But how can i proof that type by officially unlike the first thing I said.Is there a software that does this ?

Answer (score 0):

The EtherType field identifies the *payload protocol*, not the Ethernet protocol (as there's only a single Ethernet data link layer). The EtherType enables the system's interface handler to pass those frames to the according network stack.

E.g. IPv4 uses an EtherType of 0x0800, PROFINET uses 0x8892. So, frames with those EtherType values are passed to the appropriate, registered handler. When a frame with an unknown (unregistered) EtherType is received the frame is simply ignored.